# Como identificar numero decimal y entero en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenos días/tarde/noche, llego aquí con al pregunta de como identificar numero decimal y entero en python. Porque ingreso números con el float en caso de que ingrese el usuario numero decimal. Entonces quiero que muestre numero entero en caso de que el usuario haya ingresa numero entero y que muestre decimal en caso de que haya ingresa un numero decimal. 
Gracias por la atención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python asigna el tipo de dato de manera dinamica, si el usuario te ingresa un entero python el resto del programa lo tratara como entero, al igual que si es un float. Por lo tanto si hacemos un print de la variable que almacena la entrada, esta se mostrara como tal.

Podes probar el siguiente programa y ver como funciona:

```
#Pedir el dato
dato = input('Ingrese dato: ') #Intenta introducir primero un entero y luego un decimal

print(type(dato)) #Ver de que tipo de dato es la variable
print(dato)
```

Lo que te mostrara es que tanto si ingreso un entero como un decimal python lo va a tomar como un string, luego si quieres hacer algun tipo de calculo con esa variable tendrias que castearla: `print(int(dato))` o `print(float(dato))`

Comment: Entiendo, me dices que para hacer proceso debo poner print(int(dato)) pero eso en caso de ser entero, pero como la identifico si es decimal o entero.

Comment: En python3, `input` devuelve siempre un objeto `str`, equivalente al `raw_input` de python2 que, creo, que es para lo que habías pensado este código.

Answer (score 2):

Esta puede ser una forma de "deducir" el tipo de dato.

Recuerda que input recibe **str (String)**, es decir, texto puro. Depende de ti convertir ese texto en el tipo de dato que quieras.

Este código solo inspecciona si hay un "." (punto) en dicho texto ingresado:

```
dato = input('Ingrese dato: ')

if '.' in dato:
    print("Seguramente es decimal", dato)
    print(type(dato))
else:
    print("Seguramente es entero", dato)
    print(type(dato))
```

**Salida** para "5.2" (str)

```
Ingrese dato: 5.2
Seguramente es decimal 5.2
<class 'str'>
```

**Salida** para "3" (str)

```
    Ingrese dato: 3
Seguramente es entero 3
<class 'str'>
```

En el if-else tendrías que convertir el tipo de dato str al tipo de dato respectivo.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando la respuesta de @Reynald0, no es suficiente con comprobar si la entrada tiene un punto `'.'`. También serían `float` números como `1e100`, `1e-2` e `inf`.

Mi consejo es ir comprobado conversiones y errores de esta forma:

```
dato = input("Ingrese dato: ")

num = None
for conv in (int, float, complex):
    try:
        num = conv(dato)
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

if num is None:
    print("Error de entrada")
else:
    print(f"dato={num} (tipo: {type(num).__name__})")
```

Answer (score 2):

isinstance(object, classinfo) : Identifica si un objeto pertenece a una clase

```
numero = 123.456
print (numero)
print (type(numero))
if isinstance(numero, complex):
    print (numero, ' es un número complejo')
elif isinstance(numero, float):
    print (numero, ' es un número es real')
elif isinstance(numero, int):
    print (numero, ' es un número es entero')
elif isinstance(numero,str):
    print (numero, ' es una cadena')
# etc...
else:
    print(numero,' es un completo misterio')
```

Answer (score 0):

Para identificar si un número entero tiene parte decimal se usal la función [is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) perteneciente al tipo float.

```
136.555.is_integer()
False
136.0.is_integer()
True
```

Answer (score -1):

ok so you can do something much more easy than that and that works better:

```
num = float(input("num: ")
if num == float:
    print("it has decimals")
elif num == int:
    print("it doesn't have decimals")
else:
    print("you messed up")
```

yeah thats it, it works great try it, or not i dont really care

Comment: Estás es [es.so]. El idioma oficial del sitio es el español. Además, explica tu respuesta, no basta decir "realmente no me importa" ("I don't really care"), sino que realmente debes explicar cómo funciona. Revisa las demás respuestas, que son más explicativas.

Comment: @Antonio Galicia: debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien la traduzca.